# Django call a function without an accessible URL?

Tags: django, templates, url

Say I want to delete a record on the website. I just want a single button that calls a function that's like "delete_record" or something.

But also say I DON'T want that function call to be accessible via any URL people can type into the browser.

Can this be done?

I just think it's kind of insecure to have a URL that's like "/delete_record/12345" just laying out there for anyone to type in. Yes I can double-triple check to see if the guy actually has access to it, but still very strange.

Comment: If URL cannot resolve to that view, you _cannot_ access that view from the web interface. You would just have a view sitting there, doing nothing.

Comment: OK so the answer is "no" =) That's good to know, since I suppose a browser accesses everything through URLs.

Comment: Well except for one scenario - which is, one view method calling another. Which you can avoid by not coding it that way :)

Comment: Why would you write a view if you don't want it to be accessible in the first place? Maybe you should write a command instead.

Comment: @François: how do I write a "command" ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 0):

> But also say I DON'T want that function call to be accessible via any URL people can type into the browser.

You could have a hidden form with `pk` of the object you want to delete, and have the form submit when a user clicks on the delete link. Since the form is POSTed, the delete url won't do any good if someone types it into the browsers address bar.

But I think it would be a lot lot better to use an ajax link which sends a `DELETE` instead of `GET`. That would also make typing the url into the address bar useless.

Comment: Could you point me to something that describes such an AJAX link?